# Transition path length with marker in D3.js makes markers vanish

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, transition

I have [this graph of nodes and shapes created with D3.js](https://jsfiddle.net/asbjornu/j10qfboc/) that I'm having trouble animating. What I want to do is transition the length of the paths, but when I do that, the `path`'s `marker-end` disappears.

I've managed to `append()` an `svg:animate` element to accomplish almost the same thing, but I'm thinking it's better to use D3's `transition()` to actually set the `path`'s `d` attribute. Can anyone tell me why the markers vanish from the paths when they are animated with `transition()`?

```
var graph = d3.select('.graph')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', window.innerWidth)
    .attr('height', window.innerHeight);

var defs = graph.append('svg:defs');

var blueGradient = defs.append('svg:linearGradient')
    .attr('id', 'b')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', 0)
    .attr('y2', 1)
    .attr('spreadMethod', 'pad');

blueGradient.append('svg:stop')
    .attr('offset', '0%')
    .attr('stop-color', '#e4f5fc')
    .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

blueGradient.append('svg:stop')
    .attr('offset', '100%')
    .attr('stop-color', '#2ab0ed')
    .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

var orangeGradient = defs.append('svg:linearGradient')
    .attr('id', 'o')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', 0)
    .attr('y2', 1)
    .attr('spreadMethod', 'pad');

orangeGradient.append('svg:stop')
    .attr('offset', 0)
    .attr('stop-color', '#f6e6b4')
    .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

orangeGradient.append('svg:stop')
    .attr('offset', '100%')
    .attr('stop-color', '#ed9017')
    .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

var arrow = defs.append('svg:marker')
    .attr('id', 'arrow')
    .attr('orient', 'auto')
    .attr('markerWidth', 2)
    .attr('markerHeight', 4)
    .attr('refX', 0.1)
    .attr('refY', 2);

arrow.append('path')
    .attr('d', 'M0,0 V4 L2,2 Z')
    .attr('fill', '#aaa');

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { console.log(d); return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { console.log(d); return d.y; });

var appended = false;
var step = -1;

document.addEventListener('keydown', drawGraph);
document.addEventListener('click', drawGraph);

drawGraph();

function drawGraph(event) {
    var nodes = [
        {
            x: 200,
            y: 50,
            c: 'b',
        },
        {
            x: 400,
            y: 50,
            c: 'b'
        },
        {
            x: 600,
            y: 50,
            c: 'b'
        },
        {
            x: 725,
            y: 175,
            c: 'b'
        },
        {
            x: 600,
            y: 300,
            c: 'o'
        },
        {
            x: 400,
            y: 300,
            c: 'o'
        },
        {
            x: 200,
            y: 300,
            c: 'o'
        },
        {
            x: 75,
            y: 175,
            c: 'o'
        }
    ];

    switch (step) {
        case -1:
            var paths;

            if (!appended) {
                paths = graph.selectAll('path.nodes')
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append('path')
                    .attr('stroke', '#aaa')
                    .attr('stroke-width', 10)
                    .attr('fill', 'none')
                    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)');

                graph.selectAll('circle.nodes')
                    .data(nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append('svg:circle')
                    .attr('cx', function(d) {
                        return d.x;
                    })
                    .attr('cy', function(d) {
                        return d.y;
                    })
                    .attr('r', 19)
                    .attr('fill', function(d) {
                        return 'url(#' + d.c + ')';
                    })
                    .attr('stroke', function(d) {
                        switch (d.c) {
                            case 'b':
                                return '#2E75B6';
                            case 'o':
                                return '#BF9000';
                        }
                    });
            } else {
                paths = graph.selectAll('path')
                    .transition();
            }

            paths.attr('d', function(currentNode, i) {
                if (!currentNode) {
                    return;
                }

                if (appended) {
                    // For some reason, the index is base 0 when the elements
                    // are appended, then 1 based afterwards.
                    i--;
                }

                currentNode = nodes[i];

                var nextNode = i < nodes.length - 1 ?
                    nodes[i + 1] :
                    nodes[0];

                startPath = {
                    x: currentNode.x,
                    y: currentNode.y,
                    c: currentNode.c
                };

                endPath = {
                    x: nextNode.x,
                    y: nextNode.y,
                    c: nextNode.c
                };

                return line([startPath, endPath]);
            });

            appended = true;
            step++;
            break;

        case 0:
            graph.selectAll('path')
                .transition()
                .attr('d', function(currentNode, i) {
                    if (!currentNode) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // For some reason, the index is suddenly base 1, not 0.
                    i--;

                    var nextNode = i < nodes.length - 1 ?
                        nodes[i + 1] :
                        nodes[0];

                    startPath = {
                        x: currentNode.x,
                        y: currentNode.y,
                        c: currentNode.c
                    };

                    endPath = {
                        x: nextNode.x,
                        y: nextNode.y,
                        c: nextNode.c
                    };
                    var diff = {
                        x: nextNode.x - currentNode.x,
                        y: nextNode.y - currentNode.y
                    };

                    var margins = {
                        current: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0
                        },
                        next: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0
                        }
                    };

                    if (diff.x > 0 && diff.y === 0) {
                        margins.current.x = 30;
                    } else if (diff.x < 0 && diff.y === 0) {
                        margins.current.x = -30;
                    } else if (diff.x > 0) {
                        margins.current.x = 20;
                    } else if (diff.x < 0) {
                        margins.current.x = -20;
                    }

                    if (diff.y > 0 && diff.x === 0) {
                        margins.current.y = 30;
                    } else if (diff.y < 0 && diff.x === 0) {
                        margins.current.y = -30;
                    } else if (diff.y > 0) {
                        margins.current.y = 20;
                    } else if (diff.y < 0) {
                        margins.current.y = -20;
                    }

                    if (margins.current.x != 0) {
                        margins.next.x = margins.current.x < 0 ?
                            Math.abs(margins.current.x * 1.5) :
                            margins.current.x * -1.5;
                    }

                    if (margins.current.y != 0) {
                        margins.next.y = margins.current.y < 0 ?
                            Math.abs(margins.current.y * 1.5) :
                            margins.current.y * -1.5;
                    }

                    startPath.x += margins.current.x;
                    startPath.y += margins.current.y;
                    endPath.x += margins.next.x;
                    endPath.y += margins.next.y;

                    return line([startPath, endPath]);
                });

            step--;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this in the `else` condition...

```
paths = graph.selectAll('path')
```

... you are selecting the markers as well, and that is not what you want.

Solution: give your paths a class...

```
.attr("class", "nodes")
```

... and select by that class:

```
paths = graph.selectAll('.nodes')
```

Alternatively, create a proper "update" selection (look at the *Post Scriptum* below).

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khukeh13/

**PS**: I made a slow transition just for you to see that the markers are moving. However, you still have a lot of problems in that code (look at the errors in console), not related with the current question and that may be worth a new question. The errors are related to that strange mix of `switch` and `if`, which I advise you to get rid of. You don't need that: just create a basic "enter", "update" and "exit" selections, that's the idiomatic D3 way of doing it.

Comment: I understand the code isn't ideal, but the reason I have the `switch` is because the code is taken from a Reveal.js presentation where each "fragment step" within a slide is going to advance the state of the graph.

Also, I don't quite understand how `.selectAll('path')` can select an element that isn't named `path`. Can you please explain?

Lastly, the transition now reduces the path to nothing. That did not happen before adding the class name. Can you please explain why?

Comment: But the arrow **is** a path. Have a look at this in your code:  `arrow.append('path').attr('d', 'M0,0 V4 L2,2 Z').attr('fill', '#aaa');`.

Comment: `selectAll("path")` select all `path` elements in the selection. Regarding the transition, as I told you in the PS, that's because you have some problems with the counters you are using in your switch.